# How to restore Firefox cache after restarting pc

Tags: firefox

I downloaded .MKV file in Firefox using "open with VLC media player". After restarting my PC I couldn't find it.
i found that it saved in Firefox cache/Tmp files.
how can i restore them ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that it's the same file then Rename it and add .MKV at the end of it, you should able to open it with other media players

also here is a complete guideline :
https://www.easeus.com/file-recovery/view-and-restore-firefox-cache-temp-files.html